# extract consecutive rows with similar values in a column more with a specific patch size

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I was looking out to extract consecutive rows with specified text repeated continuously for more than 5 times.

ex:

```
 A  B   C 
10  john    1
12  paul    1
23  kishan  1
12  teja    1
12  zebo    1
324 vauh    -1
3434    krish   -1
232 poo -1
4535    zoo 1
4343    doo 1
342 foo -1
123 soo 1
121 koo -1
34  loo -1
343454  moo -1
565343  noo -1
2323234 voo -1
3434    coo 1
545 xoo 1
6565    zoo 1
232321  qoo 1
34454   woo 1
546556  eoo 1
65665   roo -1
5343    too -1
3232    yoo 1
1212    uoo 1
23355667    ioo 1
787878  joo -1
```

I am looking out for the below result where the column value 'c' has consecutive 1's repeated more than 4 times as different groups .

Output:

```
A   B   C   group
10  john    1   1
12  paul    1   1
23  kishan  1   1
12  teja    1   1
12  zebo    1   1
3434 coo    1   2
545  xoo    1   2
6565    zoo 1   2
232321  qoo 1   2
34454   woo 1   2
546556  eoo 1   2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using masks and [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
# identify 1s
m = df['C'].eq(1)
# group consecutive values
g = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()
# identify stretches of 5+ 1s
m2 = m & df.groupby(g)['C'].transform('size').ge(5)

out = (df.loc[m2]
         .assign(group=pd.factorize(g[m2])[0]+1)
       )
```

Output:

```
         A       B  C  group
0       10    john  1      1
1       12    paul  1      1
2       23  kishan  1      1
3       12    teja  1      1
4       12    zebo  1      1
17    3434     coo  1      2
18     545     xoo  1      2
19    6565     zoo  1      2
20  232321     qoo  1      2
21   34454     woo  1      2
22  546556     eoo  1      2
```

Comment: Thanks much, this is what I was really looking out for. For me, I had to change the code to below `m2 = m & df.groupby(g).C.transform('size').ge(5)`

Answer (score 4):

You can `groupby` the difference of col C, get the `cumsum` where the difference does not equal zero and transform the size of each group so you can only keep the groups that are greater than or equal to five

```
df[df['C'].eq(1) & df.groupby(df['C'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()).transform('size').gt(4)]

         A       B  C
0       10    john  1
1       12    paul  1
2       23  kishan  1
3       12    teja  1
4       12    zebo  1
17    3434     coo  1
18     545     xoo  1
19    6565     zoo  1
20  232321     qoo  1
21   34454     woo  1
22  546556     eoo  1
```

If you want a group column

```
# create the groups by calculating the diff and getting the cumsum
df['group'] = df['C'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
# boolean indexing to keep values where C == 1 AND the size of each group is greater than 4
df[df['C'].eq(1) & df.groupby('group').transform('size').gt(4)]

         A       B  C  group
0       10    john  1      1
1       12    paul  1      1
2       23  kishan  1      1
3       12    teja  1      1
4       12    zebo  1      1
17    3434     coo  1      7
18     545     xoo  1      7
19    6565     zoo  1      7
20  232321     qoo  1      7
21   34454     woo  1      7
22  546556     eoo  1      7
```